# Jquery Selector not working in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery

For the following HTML

```
<div id='parent'> 
  <input id='child' type=hidden value=''/>
</div>
```

I am doing

```
$('#parent #child').val('test')
```

OR

```
$('#parent > #child').val('test')
```

but none of the above is working in IE7. It does work in Firefox though

Any idea why is it not working ?

Comment: You could try using `.attr("value")` ? Not sure if that's the issue or not but perhaps worth a try?

Comment: How do you know it is *not working*? What should happen? Setting the value with `val` will not change the *source code*. Btw, using `$('#child')` is easier and more correct.

Comment: I dont't know why it's not working but why do you do this? `id` is unique, so just use `$('#child')`.

Comment: Both should work. How do you know that's not working? How you inspect the value of the hidden field after calling your script?

Answer (score 1):

is it because you've got the HTML wrong? You should use " for attribute values. Sometimes IE is more sensitive to these things than Firefox

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax seems correct. The only stuff I can think of that can muck this up are:

- Make sure you've got your code between a `$(document).ready()` block
- Maybe try `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` if you're using jQuery 1.6+

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('#child').val('test');` which would probably give the same result.